# different outputs for the same function

Tags: javascript

Can someoen please explain the different outputs for this 2 functions?

```
var reverse = function(string) {
    var myArray = string.split('').reverse().join('');
    return myArray;
}

alert(reverse("this is a string")); // gnirts si a siht



var reverse = function(string) {
    var myArray = string.split('');
    myArray.reverse();
    myArray.join('');
    return myArray;
}

alert(reverse("this is a string")); // g,n,i,r,t,s, ,s,i, ,a, ,s,i,h,t
```

Comment: `myArray.join('');` does not alter the `myArray` variable or the array object itself. You want `myArray = myArray.join('');`

Answer (score 1):

In the second function, you are splitting a string, then returning the reversed array.

The `.join()` method doesn't alter the `myArray` variable it is operating on, thus it's like `.join()` isn't even being called. In other words,

```
myArray.join('');
```

isn't the same as:

```
myArray = myArray.join('');
```

This will give you the same results as your first function:

```
var reverse = function(string) {
    var myArray = string.split('');
    myArray.reverse();
    myArray = myArray.join('');
    return myArray;
}
```

..or you could just return the joined array:

```
return myArray.join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your second function is that you need to reassign result of join operation (or simply return `myArray.join('')`), otherwise it doesn't mutate original `myArray`. So you just return reversed array, not a string. What happens next is that `alert` calls `toString` method internally which is equivalent to `myArray.join()` (note, `join` is without arguments), which is the same as join(',') by default.

Correct code would be

```
var reverse = function(string) {
    var myArray = string.split('');
    myArray.reverse();
    myArray = myArray.join(''); // or simply return myArray.join(','); 
    return myArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `myArray.join('')` in your second function return a string in your case you are not asigning it to variable just return an array. It will return same results if you changed your code like this.

```
var reverse = function(string) {
    var myArray = string.split('');
    myArray.reverse();
    myArray = myArray.join('');
    return myArray;
}
```